# Under what conditions can one make the following function continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose, I have a continuous function on an open subset $S$ of the reals (can be taken to be a finite union of open intervals):
$$f \colon S \rightarrow \mathbb R$$

Such that, for every $y \in f(S)$, we have $o(f^{-1}(\{y\})) = 2$.

Next, I define the injective function that transposes the elements of the inverse of $f$:
$$\psi(f) \colon S \rightarrow S ~~~\text{as}~~~ x \mapsto x' ~~\text{iff}~~f(x)=f(x')$$

(A thing to notice is: $\psi(f)^2= Id_S$)

That is, if we define 
$$f^{-} \colon f(S) \rightarrow S ~~~\text{as}~~~ y \mapsto \min\{f^{-1}(y)\}$$ 
and 
$$f^{+} \colon f(S) \rightarrow S ~~~\text{as}~~~ y \mapsto \max\{f^{-1}(y)\}$$

Then,
$$ \psi(f)(x) = f^{-}(x)+f^{+}(x)-x$$

> I have tried to prove that $\psi(f)$ is continuous under these conditions and have failed. Can this be proved? Or what 'minimal' hypotheses can I add to make it become so except for making $S$ compact?

Comment: just a note: the only open compact subset of the reals is the empty set.

Comment: @rewritten I meant making S compact (non-trivially) would force $\psi(f)$ to become a homeomorphism if it became continuous.

Comment: Are they all open intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry that the answer is a bit long. I just want to make things clear to me.

Assume that $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb R$ is continuous so that for all $E$ in the image of $f$, the set $f^{-1}(E)$ has at most two elements.

**Claim 1**: Any interior maximum/minimum (if exists) must be global maximum/minimum.

**Proof of claim 1**: Let $c\in (a, b)$ be an interior maximum. Then $f(x) \leq f(c):=E$ whenever $x$ is close to $c$. Assume the contrary that $c$ is not a strict maximum. Then there is $ d\in (a, b)$ so that $f(d) \geq E$. Assume $d>c$ (the other case is similar). As $c$ is interior maximum, there is $y_1 < c<y_2<d$ so that $f(y_1), f(y_2)<E$. By intermediate value theorem there are

$$y_1<x_1<c<  x_2 < y_2 <x_3< d \text{ and  } F \in (\max\{ f(y_1), f(y_2)\}, E)$$

so that $f(x_1) = f(x_2) = f(x_3) = F$. That is not possible by assumption. Thus Claim 1 is proved.

**Claim 2**: Let $f: (a, b) \to \mathbb R$ be continuous so that for all $E$ in the image of $f$, the set $f^{-1}(E)$ has at most two elements. Then $f$ is one of the following types:

- I: $f$ is injective (thus monotone),
- II: there is $c\in (a, b)$ so that $f$ (or $-f$) attains strict minimum at $c$, and is decreasing when restricted to $(a, c)$ and increasing in $(c, b)$ respectively. (like $f(x) = \pm x^2$), or
- III: there is $(c_1, c_2) \in (a, b)$ so that $f$ (or $-f$) attains strict maximum at $c_1$ and strict minimum at $c_2$. Also $f$ is increasing in $(a, c_1)$ and $(c_2, b)$ and is decreasing in $(c_1, c_2)$. Also $\lim_{x\to a} f(a) \geq \lim_{x \to b} f(x)$ (like $f(x) = \pm \sin x $ when restricted to $(\epsilon, \pi +\epsilon)$ for $\epsilon \geq 0$)

**Proof of Claim 2**: assume that $f$ is not injective. Thus by assumption there is exactly $c, d \in (a, b)$, $c<d$ so that 
$$f(c) = f(d) = E.$$
As $(c, d)$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, either $f(x) >E$ or $f(x)<E$ in $(c, d)$. Assume the former holds (the other case is similar), let $e\in (c, d)$ so that $f$ attains its maximum in $(c, d)$. Let $F = f(e)$. For all $y\in (E, F)$, there is $e_1 \in (c, e)$ and $e_2 \in (e, d)$ so that $f(e_1) = f(e_2) = y$. Thus $f$ is strictly increasing in $(c, e)$ and strictly decreasing in $(e, b)$.

Now we consider the interval $(d, b)$. By continuity of $f$, either $f(x) >E$ and $f(x) <E$ for all $x\in (d, b)$. The former case is not possible there is already two elements in $(c, d)$ with image $y >E$. Thus $f(x) <E$. There are two cases:

(a) $f$ is not injective when restricted to $(d, b)$, we can find a interior extremum $g\in (d, b)$ as in the previous paragraph. By claim 1, this is a global minimum. Then one can show that $f$ is injective in $(a, e)$, $(e, g)$ and $(g, b)$ (or we can find yet another extremum). The limit
$$\lim_{x\to a} f(a) \geq \lim_{x \to b} f(x)$$

can be proved by (for example) contradiction and intermediate value theorem. Thus $f$ is of type III.

(b) If $f$ is injective when restricted to $(d, b)$. Then it must be strictly decreasing. Thus we turn our attention to $(a, c)$. If it is also injective, then it is strictly increasing and $f$ is of type II. If not, then there is a global minimum at $g\in (a, c)$. Thus $-f$ is of type III. Thus claim 2 is proved.

Now we can go back to your question. Decompose $f: S \to \mathbb R$ into several functions $f_i :(a_i, b_i) \to \mathbb R$, $i = 1, \cdots, N$ such that the intervals are pairwise disjoint and 
$$S = \cup_i^N (a_i, b_i).$$ 
Given that for any $E$ in the image of $S$, there is exactly two elements in $f^{-1}(E)$. Then all $f_i$ satisfy the assumptions in claim 1, 2 and so they are of type I, II, or III.

**Claim 3**: $f_i$ cannot be of type III for all $i$.

**Proof of claim 3** If $f_i: (a_i, b_i) \to \mathbb R$ is of type III, then for any $y$ in the closed interval

$$[A_i, B_i]= [\lim_{x\to a_i} f_i(x), \lim_{x\to b_i} f_i(x)]$$

there is exactly one $x\in (a_i, b_i)$ so that $f_i(x) = y$. In particular, there is some $j \neq i$ and $x' \in (a_j, b_j)$ so that $f_j(x') = B_i$. But now as the image of $f_j$ must lie in $[A_i, B_i]$, and has to be injective. This is impossible for both three types. Thus such a $j$ does not exist and that finishes the proof of claim 3.

**Claim 4** If $f_i$ is of type II, then 
$$A_i := \lim_{x\to a_i} f_i(x) = \lim_{x\to b_i} f_i(x):=B_i . $$

**Proof of claim 4**: 
Assume $f_i$ is of type II and attains a maximum. Assume the contrary that $A_i > B_i$ (The other case $A_i < B_i$ is similar). Then there is $x\in (a_i, b_i)$ so that $f_i(x) = B_i$. By definition of $f$, there is $j\neq i$ and $y\in (a_j, b_j)$ so that $f_j(y) = B_i$. Thus $f_j$ has a interior maximum at $y$. This mean that $f_j$ is of type II. This mean that there is $y_1, y_2 \in (a_j, b_j)$, $y_3 \in (a_i, b_i)$ and $G \in (A_i, B_i)$ so that

$$f_j(y_1) = f_j(y_2) = f_i(y_3) = G.$$

This contradicts to your assumption and thus claim 4 is shown.

Now we can answer one of your question asked in the comment.

**Theorem 1** $N$, the number of component of $S$, must be even.

**Proof of theorem 1**: Let $E$ be in the image of $f$. Then there is $x \in (a_i, b_i)$ and $y\in (a_j, b_j)$ so that $x\neq y$ and $f(x) = f(y)=E$. There are two cases.

(i) $i=j$. In this case, $f_i$ is of type II (As type I function are injective). Let $B$ be the maximum of $f_i(x)$. Then there is $j' \neq i$ so that $f_{j'}$ is of type II and attains minimum $B$. Thus the image of $f_i$ and $f_{j'}$ forms an open intervals, and if $k \neq i, j'$, then the image of $f_k$ is not in this interval by claim 4. (This is the case described in rewritten's answer)

(ii) $i \neq j$. If $f_i$ attains extremum at $x$, then everything reduces to case (i). This shows that $f_i$ and so $f_j$ are both of type I, and image of $f_i= $ image of $f_j$.

Note that in both cases (i), (ii), the $f_i$ comes in pairs. So we can take away this two indices and consider the remaining $N-2$ one. This shows that $N$ must be even.

Now we come to the main theorem. That completely answer your question.

**Theorem 2** $\psi (f)$ is continuous if and only if $f_i$ is monotone for all $i=1, \cdots, N$.

**Proof of Theorem 2**:  Theorem 1 tells us that we can group $f_i$ into pairs $(f_1, f_2)$, ... , $(f_{N-1}, f_N)$ so that in each pairs, the functions are of the same type (I or II). Thus it suffices to consider $N=2$.

If $f_1, f_2$'s are of type I, then $f^{-1}_1, f^{-1}_2$ are also continuous

$$\psi (f)|_{(a_2, b_2)} = f^{-1}_1 \circ f_2, \ \ \ \psi(f)|_{(a_1, b_1)} = f^{-1}_2\circ f_1$$

Thus $\psi(f)$ is continuous.

If both $f_1, f_2$ are of type II, then an argument similar as in rewritten's answer shows that $\psi(f)$ cannot be continuous. This finishes the proof of Theorem 2.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the effort. This will take some time to digest. But, now its really past my bedtime so I'll come back to it tomm.

Comment: This is a really great (and thorough) answer! Wish I could give you more points.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the following function defined in $S=(-3, -1)\cup(1, 3)$:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = -|x+2| & \:\text{ when }x < 0 \\
f(x) = |x-2| & \:\text{ when }x > 0
\end{align}
$$

The graph of this function covers exactly twice the open interval $(-1, 1)$, and the preimages of $0$ are $-2$ and $2$.

From this $f$, the function $\psi$ is not continuous, as it preserves the two intervals, except for the central points which are interchanged:

$$
\psi(2\pm\epsilon) = 2\mp\epsilon \\
\psi(2) = -2
$$

This counstruction can be done whenever you have a disconnected set, so you actually need a connected set to guarantee continuity of $\psi$. But a connected open set of reals can't have a function $f$ like you describe.

Comment: Nice! But, are you sure this construction will work for disconnected sets with odd number of components?

Comment: For $f$ to be as the hypothesis, the number of components must be even, see @John's answer for the details.